# How to integrate sweetalert2 with cakephp form

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am very new to cakephp framework and i am trying to use sweetalert confirmation instead of normal javascript confirm method. But i have no clue how to integrate this with cakephp form.

```
 $this->Form->postLink(
                __('Withdraw'),
                ['action' => 'request'],
                ['confirm' => __('Are you sure?'), 'class' => 'btn btn-outline-dark mb-0 ms-auto']
            );
```

The above confirm element creates below code where form name is created on random by cakephp.

[image]

I want to replace confirm method with sweetalert confirmation which is provided below

```
Swal.fire({  
  title: 'Are you sure?',  
  showCancelButton: true,  
  confirmButtonText: `Yes`,  
  denyButtonText: `No`,
}).then((result) => {   
    if (result.isConfirmed) {    
        //Proceeds to submit form
    } else if (result.isDenied) {    
        //Just closing the confirmation  
    }
});
    }
```

cakephp version: 3.10.1

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: my bad.. Here is the version of cakephp i am using 3.10.1

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the `confirmJs` form helper template to use custom JS.

For `FormHelper::postLink()` calls the template will, among others, receive the template variables `confirmMessage`, which is a JSON string with the confirm message, and `formName`, which is a literal string holding the form name. For `FormHelper::button()` calls there will be no `formName`, so you'd need to take that into account if you want to support that usage too!

While you could put the whole sweet alert code in the `confirmJs` template, I'm not sure that all browsers do finally support linebreaks in HTML attributes, so to be on the safe side you may want to use a helper function (it's also more readable).

For example:

```php
<script>
    function swalConfirm(buttonOrLink, message, formName) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: message,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: `Yes`,
            denyButtonText: `No`,
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                //Proceeds to submit form
                if (formName) {
                    // it's a `postLink` form
                    document[formName].submit();
                } else if (buttonOrLink.form) {
                    // it's a regular form
                    buttonOrLink.form.submit();
                } else {
                    // it's something that shouldn't exist,
                    // possibly a form button outside a form...
                }
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                //Just closing the confirmation
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<?php
$this->Form->setTemplates([
    'confirmJs' => 'swalConfirm(this, {{confirmMessage}}, "{{formName}}"); event.returnValue = false; return false;',
]);
?>
```

Then you could simply use your `postLink()` call as-is:

```php
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    __('Withdraw'),
    ['action' => 'request'],
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure?'), 'class' => 'btn btn-outline-dark mb-0 ms-auto']
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**

ps. Note that as of CakePHP 4, the `confirmMessage` template variable will not be a JSON string anymore, but an HTML entity encoded string literal, so you'd have to explicitly put it in quotes:

```php
'swalConfirm(this, "{{confirmMessage}}", "{{formName}}")',
```

or use the `data-confirm-message` attribute that has been introduced with 4.x:

```php
'swalConfirm(this, this.getAttribute("data-confirm-message"), "{{formName}}")',
```

or for modern browsers:

```php
'swalConfirm(this, this.dataset.confirmMessage, "{{formName}}")',
```